# Normal distribution. Doubt

Tags: normal-distribution

If $Y$ is Normal($\mu$=0, $\sigma$=1), can it happen that, for a positive constant $\alpha$:
$$\Pr[Y\gt2\alpha]=0 \text{ ?}$$

Comment: What do you think?  Why do you doubt your answer?

Comment: Since I was trying to understand what happens if I take $\alpha$=$\infty$

Comment: $\infty$ is not a positive real number and so need not be considered.  I will point out that when we say that many things in real life can be modeled by normal distributions, the word *modeled* here implies that we understand that the results might not perfectly match a normal distribution but that it closely approximates what we see.  For example, when talking about the height of a person.  Of course we know it is impossible for a person to have negative height, though the model would predict that there is a positive probability (*albeit incredibly small*) that a person has negative height.

Comment: Ok, perfect, the problem is that I was convinced that $\infty$ can be considered as  a constant. I got it now, Thank You

Comment: If you insist on talking about "*if I take $\alpha = \infty$*", about the only reasonable interpretation of this would be talking about $\lim\limits_{\alpha \to \infty} Pr[Y>2\alpha]$ which will indeed equal $0$.  This is not the same thing as letting $\alpha$ *equal* infinity however.

Comment: Ok, great. Thank You again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Note that $P(Y \gt 2\alpha) = 0 \iff P(Y \leq 2\alpha ) = 1$, and this is the standard normal distribution, so it's cdf is 
 $ P(Y \leq 2\alpha ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{2\alpha} e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt$

One can show that for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ this cdf is smaller than one, although it $\it{converges}$ to one.

Meaning that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} = 1$, but for a specific $\alpha$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{2\alpha} e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} \lt 1$

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.

For certain values of $\alpha$, this probability can get extremely small, but never zero.

The normal distribution has a PDF of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{x^2/2}$, which has positive probability even for large $x$.

Comment: And if I take $\alpha$=$\infty$?

Comment: infinity is a concept. but, $\displaystyle \lim_{\alpha \to \infty} Pr[Y > 2\alpha] = 0$

Comment: Thank You a lot